# display all values from the loop in one window

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I am using `MessageBox.Show();` to show data from a loop but it is only showing 1 value and I need to show at least 5 values.

I tried:

```
while (eN <= toE) 
{
   MessageBox.Show("EN: " + eN.ToString());
   eN += step;
}
```

When I run my program I have 1 window showing me 1 value. When I click Ok a second window appears with the next value.
I need only 1 window. How could I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I shortened your question to only contain the absolute core of your issue. I hope you don't mind. If you feel that I removed to much or disagree with my edit much you can change it back again via the `edit` button under the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate the values into the same string, then display that resulting concatenated string :

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while (eN <= toE)
{
    stringBuilder.AppendLine("EN: " + eN.ToString());
    eN += step;
}

MessageBox.Show(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use a different control, like a multi-line text box, or just concatenate all of the strings *before* calling `MessageBox`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (eN <= toE) 
{
   sb.AppendFormat("EN: {0}\n", eN);
   eN += step;
}
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```